# Ansible-container builds no docker image

Tags: docker, ansible, ubuntu-16.04, ansible-container

I am struggling with ansible-container. I have an issue similar to that found in  [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-container/issues/66) where it was suggested that docker is not configured correctly. Basically I have a bare bones example and no container is built. I have docker install on Ubuntu 16.04 as per [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/) 
and the hello world and Ubuntu bash examples both work.

Could someone point me to some documentation/references that indicate the correct docker setup and/or the best way of debugging this. It occurred to me that my dns may not be configured correctly.

I simply tuse the following commands and get the resulting error:

```
ansible-container init
ansible-container build
ansible-container run
ERROR: for ansible-container  invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"/bin/false\\\": stat /bin/false: no such file or directory\"\n"
```

Comment: can you share the playbook/ansible command which is failing?

Comment: I'm just trying to run an empty project. ansible-container init -> build -> run see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/getting_started.html#dipping-a-toe-in-starting-from-scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650219/ansible-container-builds-no-docker-image#comment70499720_41650219):

> I'm just trying to run an empty project. ansible-container init -> build -> run see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/getting_started.html#dipping-a-toe-in-starting-from-scratch

You also asked:

> Could someone point me to some documentation/references that indicate the correct docker setup and/or the best way of debugging this.

Despite the fact that asking for external documentation is off-topic on StackOverflow, you don't even bother to read the documentation you have in front of your eyes, so how do you expect that another piece of documentation would help you?

Quoting the very same page you referenced:

> Let’s look at a **working example**. [ ]
>
> ```
> ansible-container init ansible.django-gulp-nginx
> ansible-container build
> ansible-container run
> ```

---

You tried to build and run an empty skeleton. Without specifying the containers (if you opened `ansible/container.yml` you would see only comments that you need to add the content) and without writing the actual playbook (`ansible/main.yml`).

Answer (score 0):

Your `ansible/container.yml` has a line with a command like

```
command: ['/bin/false']
```

but `/bin/false` seems not present in the image written above in the same `ansible/container.yml`.
If you share your `ansible/container.yml` we can help you more.